# NSFileManager delete contents of directory

Tags: cocoa, directory, osx-snow-leopard, nsfilemanager

How do you delete all the contents of a directory without deleting the directory itself? I want to basically empty a folder yet leave it (and the permissions) intact.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

E.g. by using a directory enumerator:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:path];    
NSString *file;

while (file = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL result = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];

    if (!result && error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Swift

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(cacheURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)

while let file = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(cacheURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check whether `removeItemAtPath:` actually failed before attempting to use the error object. At the very least, you may report more errors than you actually have.

Comment: There's a problem in your while loop, you can't declare you variable inside the while parentheses !!

Comment: @Psycho: True for Objective-C, works fine though for Objective-C++. Worth a down-vote when this isn't related to the problem and easy to fix? I don't think so...

Comment: The down vote was for the solution, just delete the whole directory by saving the permissions instead of iterating through the content.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dirToEmpty = ... //directory to empty
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirToEmpty 
                                              error:&error];

if(error) {
  //deal with error and bail.
}

for(NSString *file in files) {
    [manager removeItemAtPath:[dirToEmpty stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]
                        error:&error];
    if(error) {
       //an error occurred...
    }
}
```

Comment: `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath::` doesn't give you the full path of the contents.

Comment: There is no need to test for "." or ".." since `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error` _filters_ them out; from docs **The search is shallow and therefore does not return the contents of any subdirectories. This returned array does not contain strings for the current directory (“.”), parent directory (“..”), or resource forks (begin with “._”) and does not traverse symbolic links.**

Comment: @petert Whoa, this is a very old answer. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

in swift 2.0:

```
if let enumerator = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtPath(dataPath) {
  while let fileName = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath("\(dataPath)\(fileName)")
    }
    catch let e as NSError {
      print(e)
    }
    catch {
      print("error")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 if anyone needs it for a quick cut/paste

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let fileUrls = fileManager.enumerator(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
while let fileUrl = fileUrls?.nextObject() {
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: fileUrl as! URL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.1.1**:

```
public func deleteContentsOfFolder()
{
    // folderURL
    if let folderURL = self.URL()
    {
        // enumerator
        if let enumerator = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtURL(folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [], errorHandler: nil)
        {
            // item
            while let item = enumerator.nextObject()
            {
                // itemURL
                if let itemURL = item as? NSURL
                {
                    do
                    {
                        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(itemURL)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError
                    {
                        print("JBSFile Exception: Could not delete item within folder.  \(error)")
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print("JBSFile Exception: Could not delete item within folder.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` says:

> The search is shallow and therefore does not return the contents of any subdirectories. This returned array does not contain strings for the current directory (“.”), parent directory (“..”), or resource forks (begin with “._”) and does not traverse symbolic links.

Thus:

```
---( file != @"." && file != @".." )---
```

is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `NSFileManager` like this:

```
extension NSFileManager {
  func clearFolderAtPath(path: String) -> Void {
      for file in subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil) as? [String] ?? []  {
          self.removeItemAtPath(path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)
      }
  }
}
```

Then, you can clear the folder like this: `NSFileManager.defaultManager().clearFolderAtPath("the folder's path")`

Answer (score 1):

Georg Fritzsche answer for Swift did not work for me. Instead of reading the enumerated object as a String, read it as NSURL.

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let url = NSURL(string: "foo/bar")
let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)
while let file = enumerator?.nextObject() as? NSURL {
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(file, error: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not deleting the whole directory and recreate afterwards? Just get the file attributes and permissions before deleting it, and then recreate it with the same attributes.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the folder and run into possible problems (e.g. permissions) if you can just remove it's contents?

Comment: It's often better to scan a directory and remove files from source code since it's far more reliable to recover and report errors.