# iOS, Delete all data saved to device by app using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

I want my app to delete all the information it has saved to the device, and i was told you do this using the NSFile Manager, so i was wondering what the code was to do this?

Comment: You have the documentation, don't you?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770086/468724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ,

**folderPath** is the path of your Document Directory.

```
   NSString *folderPath;

NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:&error];  
        for (NSString *strName in dirContents) {                        
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strName] error:&error];      
        }
```

Hope it will be helpful to you

Comment: Don't forget to check if removeItemAtPath: actually failed before attempting to use the error object. At the very least, you may report more errors than you actually have.  
    NSError* err = nil;
    BOOL res;

    res = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strName] error:&error];
    if (!res && error) {
        NSLog(@"oops: %@", error);
    }